# Good NoSQL database for Write-Read Intensive Site

Tags: php, database, nosql

Ok I do have a small messaging site for my client. Well its more likely a post-comment system(created in PHP). Now my client want a system that can comment to another existing comment and add some features like liking and tagging. Another thing is the existing system is heavily used by my client in his company as they use it like a skype chat(that makes it write-read intensive). well my client want's to use open source software as possible. so I used mysql community edition.

Too much about my story... So I had a 1 week research about NoSql databases and I found it right for my requirements as my client wants to add features (that means adding and adding columns and tables from time to time.) Now these are nosql database systems that caught my eye.(well if you can suggest other nosql database system its ok)

1. MongoDB
2. CouchDB
3. Redis

Now my question is which of the three is good for my situation? I also read some bad things about those 3 nosql databases

1. MongoDB is crappy on its 2.x version
2. CouchDB is slow (my client doesn't want slow)
3. Redis is memory-based so it just writes on the disk on certain intervals. so when the system crash in the middle of the interval then the data is lost

I want to have some opinions about this and any advice that can help me to cope up with my upcoming situation

Comment: Based on the information you give you do have knowledge about relational databases and not about NoSQL databases. Now this isn't a case which is not doable in a relational database which you already have for the system I would strongly consider using the relational database you already have. Setting up NoSQL directly for a client and developing a company critical application doesn't feel like the right path for your project. First get the knowledge and experience before deploying it to a client project is my opinion.

Comment: @LucFranken yeah but what im worrying about is the comment-comment system. well it will make my rows reference and reference to each other... anyways thank you for your nice answer

Comment: Yes, you might be totally right from a technical perspective but also consider the business side of the case since that will be the customer experience, not the technical choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is a popular solution to this, and my personal preference. The great thing about Mongo (besides being schemaless) is that you can have nested/embedded documents. So for example, you can have a comment which has an array of sub-comments which each have their own arrays of sub-comments. I don't know of any other datastore that has that feature. It's also fast.

CouchDB has some nice features, but Mongo is so similar and much better.

Redis is very different from the other two. It's used mostly as an alternative to memcached. So it's primarily used for temporary data. Although it has some nice pubsub features built in. A lot of people use both MongoDB and Redis, but for different things.

Comment: well mongodb is now ok in there latest 2.x version? many people says the their 2.x version is crappy..

Comment: I haven't heard anyone say that. I also don't know what you are referring to when you say "crappy"

Comment: http://luigimontanez.com/2011/mongodb-2.0-should-have-been-1.0/ well i read this one...

Comment: and this one... http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FD3xe6Jt well what i mean with "crappy" is mongodb is not yet that mature for real business implementations..

Comment: From what I can tell from the articles you mentioned, their biggest complaint is that MongoDB wasn't stable enough until 2.0. The first article specifically mentions that he thinks mongoDB is now ready for use in production. There are a lot of major companies using Mongo in production already. Based on what I know about your requirements, it sounds like Mongo would be a good fit for the commenting system. Keep in mind that we are in a new era of databases and not every database is a one-size-fits-all. Use Mongo for the comments, use MySQL for everything else.

Comment: nice answer =) thank you for giving such a wonderful enlightenment